# "Because" followed by an infinitive, comma or no comma?

Tags: commas, word-order, phrasing

A co-worker who corrects my writing used this phrase:

> Because utilizing the optimal yield of solar panels, it frequently happens that installing them outside the predetermined safe zone is required.

Is it me, or does that sentence weird and unclear because

A) It needs a comma after "Because"

B) The order of the phrasing "installing them outside the safe zone is required" is not correct?

If it matters, the original phrasing was:

> Usually, however, quite a lot solar panels are required to achieve the desired energy savings. For this reason, solar panels are often placed outside of the safe zone as well.

Comment: Your original phrasing was much clearer, simpler and *better* than your co-worker's rewording!

Comment: I would rewrite it as follows, which keeps your colleague's key words but puts them in (I think) a more easy to read sentence: *"In order to utilize the optimal yield of solar panels, it is often necessary to install them outside the predetermined safe zone"*.

Comment: The 'correction' is unacceptable. 'Because of the requirement to achieve  the optimal yield from solar panels, it frequently happens that they are installed outside the predetermined safe zone.' But I prefer your original. // I'd avoid the use of the words 'required' and 'necessary' here; people existed before solar panels were invented, and '... are necessary' connotes an unqualified  'you must have' even when there's a 'to achieve the optimal yield' earlier in the sentence.

Comment: Actually, @Reinout, what's the purpose of this text?  Are you writing *instructions* for people fitting the panels, or are you *describing* how they tend to be fitted?  And, is there an element of complaint about the fact that they're outside the "safe zone", or are you saying "It's necessary to go outside the safe zone, that's just the way it is"?

Comment: I agree the "correction" is not a correction. A comma after _because_ does nothing to salvage it.

Comment: Max Williams: The latter. That's just the way it is, is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just you, the sentence sounds weird now and the original was a lot better.

To answer your two sub-questions, no, you do not need a comma after because. You just don't, see for example this [grammar girl blog entry.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-you-start-a-sentence-with-because)

Regarding your second question, from a purely grammatical standpoint the sentence is sound, you can phrase it that way. But, purely grammatical means just that there are the right types of words in the right places.

However, it makes not much sense because not the optimal yields should be utilized, but the solar panels should be utilized. Furthermore, the main clause should content-wise have a connection to the subordinate because-clause which isn't there since that clause doesn't give any real reasoning that one would expect.

To make things short, use your original sentence.